# Why does Koheleth 12:1 use בוראיך instead of בוראך?

Tags: words, hebrew, commentaries, text, kohelet

[Koheleth 12:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3112.htm) says:

> וּזְכֹר, אֶת-**בּוֹרְאֶיךָ**, בִּימֵי, בְּחוּרֹתֶיךָ:  עַד אֲשֶׁר לֹא-יָבֹאוּ, יְמֵי הָרָעָה, וְהִגִּיעוּ שָׁנִים, אֲשֶׁר תֹּאמַר אֵין-לִי בָהֶם חֵפֶץ.    1
>
> Remember then ***thy Creator*** in the days of thy youth, before the evil days come, and the years draw nigh, when thou shalt say: 'I have no pleasure in them';

Why בוראיך (which is normally plural, "thy creators") instead of בוראך?

Comment: See http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38018&st=&pgnum=8, column 2, toward the bottom, before "את השמים ואת הארץ". (If I understood what it said, I'd post it as an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tora T'mima* (#1) says the extra *yod* is to imply that the word should be taken apart for a *d'rasha* — specifically, the *d'rasha* of *Akavya ben Mahalal'el* that takes apart the word to imply בארך (your well, i.e. where you came from), בורך (your pit, i.e. grave), and בוראך (your creator), the three things one should remember ("וזכר את בוראיך") to avoid sin.

Comment: This is a good one! Can you please provide a link (if available online)?

Comment: I don't see it online; sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an annalisis of this verse, as part of Midrash Kohelet Rabbah (in hebrew). just my section to study was the 12th chapter, that starts with this question.

I found an interesting issue: your question is not new, and is a huge problem with multiples answers, all over the history.

The Massorah deals with this, the are Biblical Manuscripts without the Yod, the Targumim (Aramaic, Greek, Latin, and modern translations) white Creator in present.

The Midrash itself deals with this theological problem too, giving Drashot. 
Critical modern commentaries also tray to fix the Massoretical text, or defend ir by arguing Magestatic Plural, ... ... ...

We have a problem, and it's awesome and rich to discover how mamy answers are for the same distourbing small letter...

Am Israel love the text and make it live!

(Sorry for my poor English, I copy part of my work in hebrew.)

here is my cloud folder with a lot of material I found to this issue. enjoy!
https://1drv.ms/f/s!Avhzo-5z909_hudUA_Pzs93snalrBw

​לְפִיכָךְ וּזְכֹר אֶת בּוֹרְאֶיךָ , תְּנֵינַן (אבות ג' א') עֲקַבְיָא בֶּן מַהַלַּלְאֵל (תנא דור א', מפורסם על ענוותנותו, סרב לעמוד כאב ב"ד מסיבות שפל רוח) אוֹמֵר

הִסְתַּכֵּל בִּשְׁלשָׁה דְּבָרִים, מֵאַיִן בָּאתָ, מִטִּפָּה סְרוּחָה. וּלְאָן אַתָּה הוֹלֵךְ, לִמְקוֹם עָפָר רִמָּה וְתוֹלֵעָה. וְלִפְנֵי מִי אַתָּה עָתִיד לִתֵּן דִּין וְחֶשְׁבּוֹן, לִפְנֵי מֶלֶךְ מַלְכֵי הַמְּלָכִים הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא.

רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי דְּסִכְנִין אָמַר, 
שְׁלָשְׁתָּן דָּרַשׁ עֲקַבְיָא מִתּוֹךְ תֵּבָה אַחַת, בּוֹרְךָ, בְּאֵרְךָ, בּוֹרַאֲךָ. בּוֹרְךָ, זוֹ לֵחָה סְרוּחָה. בְּאֵרְךָ, זוֹ רִמָּה וְתוֹלֵעָה, בּוֹרַאֲךָ, זֶה מֶלֶךְ מַלְכֵי הַמְּלָכִים הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, שֶׁאַתָּה עָתִיד לִתֵּן לְפָנָיו דִּין וְחֶשְׁבּוֹן.

לְכָךְ נֶאֱמַר וּזְכֹר אֶת בּוֹרְאֶיךָ בִּימֵי בְּחוּרֹתֶיךָ, עַד דְּחֵילָךְ עֲלָךְ.

(דבר מעניין: במקרא כתוב "בוראיך" מלא י', וזה מפתיע כי משמעו כביכול בוראים רבים.

המפרשים מתמודדים עם הקושי, ולמשל דורשים את האנומליה בקשר למשנה באבות.

דעה רווחת מפרשת ריבוי מלכותי, כגון יש' נד' ה': "כי בעליך עשיך" ועוד.

הרבה חוקרים מודרניים מצעים לתקן את נוסח המסורה ודווקא לתת כתיבים אחרים עם משמעויות שונות, בדיוק כדרך ר' יהושוע בן לוי במדרש!

אם כי אפשר לראות בתרגומים עתיקים לארמית, לטינית ויוונית, כולם מתייחסים למילה במובן יחיד,

גם מצויים כ"י של ספר קהלת שמשמיטים את הי'.

רוברט גורדיס ע' 351  ו-Anchor Bible p.352 מסכימים שבפנינו הגרסה המקורית, ושכל ניסיון לשנות את הנוסח הוא דחוק, לא הגיוני ואין צורך בכלל. מכל מקום עולם המדרש מתקיים בדרכו. 
​