# Why is the word "youth" בְּחֽוּרֹתֶ֑יךָ in the plural?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, kohelet

Why is the word "youth" בְּחֽוּרֹתֶ֑יךָ in [Kohelet 12:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16473/showrashi/true) in the plural, when the first word, the first verb in the sentence, indicates that the speaker is speaking to one person?

> **וּזְכֹר֙** אֶת־בּ֣וֹרְאֶ֔יךָ בִּימֵ֖י **בְּחֽוּרֹתֶ֑יךָ** עַ֣ד אֲשֶׁ֤ר לֹֽא־יָבֹ֨אוּ֙ יְמֵ֣י הָֽרָעָ֔ה וְהִגִּ֣יעוּ שָׁנִ֔ים אֲשֶׁ֣ר תֹּאמַ֔ר אֵֽין־לִ֥י בָהֶ֖ם חֵֽפֶץ׃
>
> **And remember** your Creator **in the days of your youth,** before the days of evil come, and years arrive, about which you will say, "I have no desire in them."

Comment: I'm not an expert at dikduk - but the first word is in the imperative form commanding us to remember, the word בְּחֽוּרֹתֶ֑יךָ is talking to the masses and is therefore in the plural - there is nothing grammatically wrong here?

Comment: @Dov should not the imperative be in the plural, too, if it is commanding "us" plural?

Comment: Ummm....over to the experts :-)

Comment: You're not also confused by בוראיך? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38850/759

Comment: We have more than one childhood in which to remember Hashem (Hamlet II, ii "Happily he's the second time come to them; for they say an old man is twice a child.")

Comment: @rosends nice, now let me see if the rabbis said the same thing.

Comment: @ninamag step one... https://www.timesofisrael.com/shakespeares-works-written-by-jewish-woman-book-claims/

Comment: @rosends maybe so, but he/she/it is not a rabbi.

Answer (score 2):

[Ibin Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ecclesiastes.12.1?lang=bi&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Ecclesiastes.12.1&lang2=bi) indicates that the plural is the normal form for a stage of life:

> מצאנו
> [נעורים](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.16.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
> [עלומים](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.89.46?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
> [זקונים](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.21.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) כלם לשון זכרים רק בחורותיך יצא מן הדרך.
>
> We find "(days of) lads" "youths" "elders" all of them in masculine plural, and only "bachelors" is an exception (being grammatically feminine plural).

I put in links to the places it seems the Ibin Ezra is referring to.

Comment: Anyone have a better translation of בחור as opposed to נער, עלם?

Comment: I think "childhood", "youth" "old age" and "bachelorhood" might be a more precise translation of the terms

Comment: I don't like childhood for נער, because we find that Yosef is called a נער at 28.

Comment: Also קְדֵשִׁים ([Job 36:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Job.36.14?lang=he) as the Ibn Ezra (apparently) understands there

Comment: @Mordechai: for that matter, Yehoshua at 42 or 56.