# Why does "like the days you went out of Egypt" deal with plural "days"?

Tags: torah-study, messiah, yetziat-mitzrayim

In the verse, [Michah 7:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Micah.7.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it says "Like the days you went out of Egypt, I'll show them {lit. "him"} wonders", which simply implies that the future redemption will be similar to that of Egypt

The question is why does it says "like the *days* you went out of Egypt", if the actual event of leaving Egypt was only in one day, as it says explicitly by the commandment to remember going out of Egypt "In order that you remember *the day* you went out of Egypt {all the days of your life...}"?

Comment: See my answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119887/19563

Comment: @mordechai interesting, although in the other verse it doesn't drastically change the implication as much, it's still referring to singular in general or plural, anther similar example is Yaakov saying "I have a donkey and an ox" even though he has many, because the simple meaning singular could include many etc.. But here if it meant singular day why wouldn't it just say "like the day"?

Answer (score 2):

The text of Micha is referencing all the plagues which took place over an extended period of time, and which were part of the leaving. The [Midrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Micah.7.15?lang=bi&with=Midrash%20Lekach%20Tov&lang2=en) says, "כמו שהביא במצרים עשר מכות שנאמר כימי צאתך מארץ מצרים אראנו נפלאות (מיכה ז טו)"

Comment: See comment to nt,'s answer

Comment: But why would you assume that it "meant singular day"? It speaks in the plural specifically to include a number of days. The singular COULD include a concept of plural, but so could a plural. What we are to remember is not identical to what this verse is referring to. We focus on the actual event of going out, but this verse speaks of the ALL the wonders which include the plagues.

Comment: but the plagues didnt involve actually going out...

Answer (score 1):

It is referring to the miracles that occurred over the entire process of leaving Egypt, from the plagues to the splitting of the sea. These took place over many days.

Comment: If so then why does the verse that tells us to remember it say "remember **the day** you went out of Egypt" and why didn't this verse say "like the days you were in Egypt", or something similar, instead of making it dependant on going out, and why is the splitting of the sea still considered going out of egypt if they already left the physical place of egypt earlier

Comment: There was the main day we physically left, and there was the months-long process of leaving overall. The commandment to remember leaving Egypt does mention the day of physically leaving, but the verse referring to miracles means all the miracles in the process, which took many days.

Comment: the actual leaving itself tho, was one day